# Troubleshoot: No internet on debian lxqt while connman is connected

Tags: debian, networking, internet, lxqt, connman

On a new debian 11 installation I get no internet, even when connman tells me that I am connected.

[image: bash outputs of ip a, ip route, ping 8.8.8.8, connmanctl state, ip link, ping www.google.de]

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

was not well configured.

Is now

```
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```